# scrolling single css column instead of full page

Tags: css, scroll, multiple-columns

At the end of the page, there should be a footer with 30px height. Above, there is the content area with 2 columns that should fill the height available (window size) and the left column should be scrollable, if needed. At the moment, the full page is scrolled instead of this single column.

How to fix this? Thanks!

```css
footer {
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}


.col1 {
  float:left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  overflow:auto;
}

.col2 {
  float:left;
  padding-left: 20px;
 
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<header>
    <h1>Headline</h1>
</header>
    <div class="ym-wrapper">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="col1">
               <p>text</p>
               <p>text</p>
               <p>text</p>
               <p>text</p>
               <p>text</p>
               <p>text</p>
               <p>text</p>
               <p>text</p>
               <p>text</p>
 
            </div>
            <div class="col2">
               text
            </div>

        </div>
        <footer></footer>
     </div>
 
</body>  
  
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this css:

html{overflow:hidden}
footer {
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}


.col1 {
  float:left;

  width:250px; 
  padding:3px; 
    position:relative
}

.content
{
height: 18000px;
   overflow:auto;
    width:250px; 
    background:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:50;
}

.col2 {
  float:left;
  padding-left: 20px;

}
```

And HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<header>
    <h1>Headline</h1>
</header>
    <div class="ym-wrapper">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="col1">
             <div class="content">
               <p>text</p>
               <p>text</p>
               <p>text</p>
               <p>text</p>
               <p>text</p>
               <p>text</p>
               <p>text</p>
               <p>text</p>
               <p>text</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col2">
               text
            </div>

        </div>
        <footer></footer>
     </div>

</body>  


</html>
```

Comment: Thanks - but in this case, no scrollbar appears at column col1 when the window size is shrinked

Comment: thanks - how can I change it that col1 uses the full height that is available, from top to the footer?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with following solution, that leverages the setting of the height via `vh`.

```css
.col1 {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.col2 {
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.ym-wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.content {
  top: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_test.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="ym-wrapper">
    <div class="col1">
      <h3>Column</h3>
      <div class="content">
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
      <h3>Column</h3>
      <div class="content">
        <p>text2</p>
        <p>text2</p>
        <p>text2</p>
        <p>text2</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>


</html>
```